# Align in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have a single, easy question:
Why does the elements not align in IE as they do in Chrome (see link) and how can I prevent this?

[Project site](http://4tajm.se)

Comment: Post your code..Dont expect from us to insepct your site

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/56yCe/

Comment: There you got the code, but in the fiddle you won't see the problem in live-preview.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/56yCe/3/ Here you can see the problem @laaposto

Comment: @tommielag Please check my answer, and see if this was what you were looking for. If it was, you should mark my answer as "accepted" via the checkmark to the left of my question, at the top, so that others can see that this question has been answered.

Comment: add clear:both to the start-images CSS class and I think you are good to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to have something to do with the navigation menu at the top of your page. It seems to render the images in the same "text line" as the navigation items. The solution to this problem would be to remove the element from the flow of the text. This can be done in a couple of ways, but I'll list the 2 easiest ones.

### `float:right;`

You can float your whole `.start-images` class to either the left or right (it won't matter, since the width is 100% anyway). This will remove it from the flow from the text, and that will prevent Internet Explorer from trying to make it fit in with the menu items. Your styles would then be:

```
.start-images {
    position: float:right;
}
```

### `position:absolute;`

Just add `position:absolute` to your `.start-images` class, and then make sure the negative margin on the following `.site-bg` is replaced with a positive margin the height of the images, and you can then remove your paddings. Your styles would then be:

```
.start-images {
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
.site-bg {
    background: #FFF;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 500px auto 60px; /* -301px auto -60px; */
    /* padding: 301px 0 120px; */
}
```

*Note: I've added/modified the styles in the existing style blocks*

This would work, because absolutely positioned elements are removed from the normal flow of the text (just like floats), so even Internet Explorer won't try to make the images fit in with the text then.

The margin on the `.site-bg` is because absolutely positioned elements *also* don't occupy any space, since they're removed from the flow of the text, so you'll have to compensate this by putting a margin on the next element, so that space that's no longer filled in is now indeed filled in. The padding is then also no longer needed, since that space is already taken up by the margins nicely.